# Changing Mocked ResultSet value each time a SQL statement is run

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing, mockrunner

I'm using Mockrunner to create a mock result set for a select statement. I have a loop that executes the select statement (which returns a single value). I want to have the result set return a different value each time, but I have been unable to find anything about how to specify the result set return value based on the times the statement has been called. Here's a pseudocode snippet of the code:

In the test Code:

```
String selectSQL = "someselectStmt";
StatementResultSetHandler stmtHandler = conn.GetStatementResultSetHandler();
MockResultSet result = stmtHandler.createResultSet();
result.addRow(new Integer[]{new Integer(1)});
stmtHandler.prepareResultSet(selectSQL, result);
```

In the Actual Target Class:

```
Integer[] Results = getResults(selectSQL);

while(Results.length != 0){
    //do some stuff that change what gets returned in the select stmt
    Results = getResults(selectSQL)
}
```

So essentially I'd like to return something like 1 on the first time through, 2 on the 2nd and nothing on the 3rd. I haven't found anything so far that I'd be able to leverage that could achieve this. The mocked select statement will always return whatever the last result set was to be associated with it (for instance if I created two MockResultSets and associated both with the same select stmt). Is this idea possible?

Comment: Are you able to use Mockito? You can create an ongoing stub which returns different values in subsequent calls.

Comment: I haven't tried Mockito. I'll look into it to see if we can leverage that in our code.

Answer (score 1):

### Looping Control Flow Working Within Java and SQL

If you're coding this one in Java, a way to make your code execution calls return different, sequenced results can be accomplished throughh a looping control flow statement such as a [do-while-loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop#Java).  This Wikipedia reference has a good discussion using the contrast of the do-while-loop between implementations in Java and also in different programming lanugages.

**Some Additional Influences through Observation:**

A clue from your work with the `Mockrunner` tool:

> The mocked select statement will always return whatever the last result set was to be associated with it (for instance if I created two MockResultSets and associated both with the same select stmt)

This is the case because the `SELECT` statement must actually change as well or else repeating the query will also repeat the result output.  A clue is that your SQL exists as a literal string value throughout the execution of the code.  Strings can be altered through code and simple string manipulations.

```
String selectSQL = "someselectStmt";
StatementResultSetHandler stmtHandler = conn.GetStatementResultSetHandler();
MockResultSet result = stmtHandler.createResultSet();
result.addRow(new Integer[]{new Integer(1)});
stmtHandler.prepareResultSet(selectSQL, result);
```

in addition to the `selectSQL` variable, also add a line for a numeric variable to keep track of how many times the SQL statement is executed:

```
Int queryLoopCount = 0;
```

In the following target class:

```
Integer[] Results = getResults(selectSQL);

while(Results.length != 0){
//do some stuff that change what gets returned in the select stmt
Results = getResults(selectSQL)
}
```

Try rewriting this `WHILE` loop control following this example. In your pseudocode, you will keep pulling the same data from the call to `getResults(selectSQL);` because the query remains the same through every pass made through the code.

### Setting up the Test Schema and Example SQL Statement

Here is a little workup using a single MySQL table that contains "testdata" output to be fed into some result set.  The `ID` column could be a way of uniquely identifying each different record or "test case"

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0acd0/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE testCaseData 
    (
     id int primary key,
     testdata_col1 int,
     testdata_col2 varchar(20),
     details varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO testCaseData
(id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details)
VALUES
(1, 2021, 'alkaline gab', 'First Test'),
(2, 322, 'rebuked girdle', '2nd Test'),
(3, 123, 'municipal shunning', '3rd Test'),
(4, 4040, 'regal limerick', 'Skip Test'),
(5, 5550, 'admonished hundredth', '5th Test'),
(6, 98, 'docile pushover', '6th Test'),
(7, 21, 'mousiest festivity', 'Last Test');

commit;
```

**Query 1  A Look at All the Test Data**:

```
SELECT id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details
  FROM testCaseData
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0acd0/1/0)**:

```
| ID | TESTDATA_COL1 |        TESTDATA_COL2 |    DETAILS |
|----|---------------|----------------------|------------|
|  1 |          2021 |         alkaline gab | First Test |
|  2 |           322 |       rebuked girdle |   2nd Test |
|  3 |           123 |   municipal shunning |   3rd Test |
|  4 |          4040 |       regal limerick |  Skip Test |
|  5 |          5550 | admonished hundredth |   5th Test |
|  6 |            98 |      docile pushover |   6th Test |
|  7 |            21 |   mousiest festivity |  Last Test |
```

**Query 2  Querying Only the First Record in the Table**:

```
SELECT id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details
  FROM testCaseData
 WHERE id = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0acd0/1/1)**:

```
| ID | TESTDATA_COL1 | TESTDATA_COL2 |    DETAILS |
|----|---------------|---------------|------------|
|  1 |          2021 |  alkaline gab | First Test |
```

**Query 3  Querying a Specific Test Record Within the Table**:

```
SELECT id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details
  FROM testCaseData
 WHERE id = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0acd0/1/2)**:

```
| ID | TESTDATA_COL1 |  TESTDATA_COL2 |  DETAILS |
|----|---------------|----------------|----------|
|  2 |           322 | rebuked girdle | 2nd Test |
```

**Query 4  Returning and Limiting the Output Set Size**:

```
SELECT id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details
  FROM testCaseData
 WHERE id < 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0acd0/1/3)**:

```
| ID | TESTDATA_COL1 |      TESTDATA_COL2 |    DETAILS |
|----|---------------|--------------------|------------|
|  1 |          2021 |       alkaline gab | First Test |
|  2 |           322 |     rebuked girdle |   2nd Test |
|  3 |           123 | municipal shunning |   3rd Test |
|  4 |          4040 |     regal limerick |  Skip Test |
```

### Writing a Parameterized SQL Statement

I do not know if this difference in syntax yields the exact same results as your pseudocode, but I am recommending it from references of code structures that I know already work.

```
set condition value before loop
do{
    // do some work
    // update condition value
}while(condition);
```

The `WHILE` condition is instead at the end of the statement and should be based on a change to a value made within the looping block.  We will now introduce the second variable, an int which tracks the number of times that the loop is iterated over:

```
String selectSQL = "someselectStmt";
String[] Results; = getResults(selectSQL);

// set condition value before loop 
queryLoopCount = 0

do{
    // do some work
    Results = getResults(selectSQL);

    // update condition value
    queryLoopCount = queryLoopcount + 1;

}while(queryLoopCount < 6);
```

Where `selectSQL` comes from:

```
SELECT id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details
  FROM testCaseData
 WHERE id = 2;
```

And adapts with a built in parameter to:

```
selectSQL = 'SELECT id, testdata_col1, testdata_col2, details
  FROM testCaseData
 WHERE id = ' + queryLoopCount;
```

Mixing the string and integer values may not be a problem as in [this reference](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/conversion/num2string.html) on concatenated(+) values suggests: Anything concatenated to a string is converted to string (eg, "weight = " + kilograms).

### Ideas for Specialized Case Requirements

- You could introduce your own numbering sequence to get the records of each case to cycle through the reference table. There are a lot of possibilities by introducing an `ORDER BY` statement and altering the key `ORDER BY` value.
- The "Skip" case.  Within the Do-While loop, add a IF-THEN statement to conditionally skip a specific record.

  ```
  set condition value before loop
  do{

      if ( queryLoopCount <> 4 ) {
      // do some work}

      // update condition value
      queryLoopCount = queryLoopCount + 1;

  }while(condition);
  ```

  Using an if-then loop, this code sample will process all test records but will skip over the record of `ID` = 4 and continue through until the while loop condition is met.

Comment: Hi Richard,

Thank you for the response. Unfortunately the way this particular code is setup I can't actually change the select statement itself. This select statement doesn't know any specific qualifiers (such as the primary ID). As such it will return a collection of rows (say 10). We then limit this return set down to the first one and then do the processing of that one item. The processing of that one item will keep it from being returned from that same select statement when it re-runs (giving us 9 results and taking the first). I was wondering if there was a way to mock this type of stmt.

Comment: Please tell me more about your output rows.  Is it possible to identify even a [composite unique key](http://rdbms.opengrass.net/2_Database%20Design/2.1_TermsOfReference/2.1.2_Keys.html)?  If not, one brute-force way to make sure a record is not picked up again when using the same SQL statement is to DELETE the processed record once it's been handled (not really recommended, but it is a possibility).  Your primary problem is that *something* persistent has to exist outside of the scope of whatever is your driving process.

Comment: Essentially the code was written in such a way that it joins on two tables and returns a set of values but only deals with one row at a time. The processing of this row deletes it from one of the joined tables so when the sql runs again it doesn't return that particular row so it will process the next row in the set. So if it returned values 1-10 it would process value 1 and the 2nd time through it would only return values 2-10 which it would then process value 2 etc etc. It's not the best code, but that's typical of legacy code sadly. Does that answer what you were looking for? I'm not sure.